# How can I add a sortable link_updated column to the Link Manager?

Tags: links, admin-menu

In the link manager there is no column for the 
    link_updated field

in

http://example.com/wp-admin/link-manager.php

How can I add this sortable column?

I've tried cobbling together something like this code:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/customizing-admin-columns-wordpress/

But I'm obviously not finding the proper filters analogous to:

```
 manage_posts_columns
```

So far I've gotten this to work by directly modifying the file

```
 class-wp-links-list-table.php
```

Which is obviously not a sustainable thing to do.

Any ideas which filters to use so I can modify this without touching the core?

Comment: The link manager was removed from WordPress years ago, which version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: 4.96. The link manager persists if your original install occurred before it was dropped. (v3.5?).

Comment: hmmm if I were you I would just build a new plugin for link management and migrate it over, a CPT and a sidebar widget would be enough, and allow you to use all the standard filters/actions